# Approach needed to solve a ABS based scenerio by ML

Tags: machine-learning

Problem Statement: Want to find out what impact Insurance markets will have if ACA (Obamacare) is repealed. This can be done by creating an ABM (agent based model) and trying out simulations. What I want to do is solve this as a machine learning problem.

The Approach I thought of is training a classifier(or an ensemble model) on pre ACA data and post ACA data and then, if it does a good job on previously unseen data, try to give it some fictional data , based upon new market conditions and see how it performs - (Sales of New policies).

There must be some better solution out there, can anyone point out to something?

Let me know if additional details are required.

Comment: This is mainly a modeling question, so I'm not sure it's within the scope of this site.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70914/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42486542/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.